# Numerical integrating regions to avoid oscillations

Tags: numerical-integration

Lets define the functions

```
osc = E^(-((I (4 x^2 - 4 y^2))/(4 \[Pi])));
const = 1/4  Sech[1/2 (-x - y)]^2 Sech[(x - y)/2]^2 Sinh[x]^2;
```

the `const` function goes to 1 as either `Abs[x]>Abs[y]` go to infinity, and is exponentially small in the other regime. while the `osc` function is just an oscillating gaussian. I want to compute the integral

```
int=NIntegrate[ osc const, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

I know that in the `Abs[x]>Abs[y]` regime, this integral should essentially be

```
Integrate[osc, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

which evaluates to `Pi^2`. while for `Abs[x]<Abs[y]` I should just get some finite contribution. However, when I try to simply compute `int` using `Nintegrate` as above, I am told that the integral does not converge, which is clearly wrong. How can I get the finite answer I expect?

Comment: i am explaining that in the regime Abs[x]>Abs[y], you can just set const=1 to good accuracy, so that the integral can be done analytically. i agree that its not exactly as i wrote, since the range of integration also needs to be restricted (i just wrote that for simplicity)

Comment: i will edit it for clarity